# Rhythmbox syncing windows games sound files. Any way to use windows media player on ubuntu?

Tags: sound, games, sync, rhythmbox

I've PC with dual OS , windows and Ubuntu.
I installed windows for games, also i installed lots of games in windows.
Except gaming i do every work on Ubuntu so i spend more time on Ubuntu.
Now problem is that when i open Rhythm-box , it syncs every sound file of games.
So in my Rhythm-box play-list more than half media files are of just games.
Its very annoying to me click on  next button 4-5 times to play music.
Also my musics are located in 'NTFS' partition.
So is there any solution available for this problem??
Also is there any way which we can install windows media player on Ubuntu??
Or any other media player which is much better than Rhythm-box and windows media player???

Sorry for bad English.

Screen-shot for reference:- http://prntscr.com/6rp055

Comment: @Da1T: Tried but i don't have 15 reputation to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like Rhythmbox.  I use Banshee instead (which comes as the default on Linux Mint and, as far as I'm concerned, should come as the default on Ubuntu).  Banshee has a similar appearance to Rhythmbox, but I find that it runs smoother and better.  You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center by simply searching Banshee.  Then, to remove Rhythmbox, you can go into the "Installed" section of the Ubuntu Software Center, click to see the Sound and Video section, click on Rhythmbox, and just click Remove.

When adding your media to Banshee, you'll go to Media>Import Media and choose to import from Folders.  Instead of importing your entire NTFS partition, go to where you actually have your music and import those folders.  By importing your entire NTFS partition, no matter which media player you use it will take anything that's on your NTFS partition, including game media.

Comment: Downloaded, looks cool.  Using it right now.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Media Player itself *can be made to work* but is not a good fit for Ubuntu. As I don't like rhythmbox neither, so I just use VLC player to play all of my media.

The advantage of VLC (for me, might be  a disadvantage to you) is that it doesn't contain a media library at all!

To remove rhythmbox and install VLC player:

```
sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox*
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: As you said your advantage is mine disadvantage.  I was looking for proper music player but nevermind problem solved, i tried different music player like amarok, tomahawk works great. Recently i switched to SM player from vlc(for videos).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **gsettings** from the terminal.

First open terminal and then you will have to find the current location with this:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb locations
```

You will get one or more paths like this `['file:///home/user/Music']`

In your case if the NTFS partition is mounted in the /dev/sda* it will something like `['file:///dev/sda*']` so you will need to choose exact folder where you have just music and not the sounds.

To change the path you need to use **set** syntax so it will look like this

```
gsettings set org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb locations "['file:///home/user2/MoreMusic']"
```